# Remove a object from a table listed inside a different table

Tags: lua, roblox

So i have 2 tables

```
local table1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
local table2 = {2,4,6,8}
```

I want remove the number in table 2 from table 1, to then use table one with the numbers removed in more code. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: remove and create a gap?  or remove and shrink the array?

Comment: remove and shrink, but it might be simpler to put the differences of the two and put that in a new table idk

Comment: There ar several ways to achieve it and complexity depends on: what are smallest and largest numbers? are arrays sorted? can be used indexed table? What did you try?

Comment: I have tried these solutions, though i may have done it wrong.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388045/difference-between-two-tables-as-a-table

I am needing to access the folder with a bunch of objects in it, out of all those object i only need certain ones to be effected.

A script generates more objects too the folder so the script as to be indirect.

I am trying to use a pre-done array from a script someone gave me, so i am not sure which type it is. However the black list object i have made the array myself, though i am not sure if its sorted or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the data into the table, set the value of the index of whatever you are reading in as the key in the table. This avoids collisions and allows easy comparisons against another table.

```
local table1 = {} 
local table2 = {}

-- read in your values as keys into the two tables
-- just an example I have no idea how you are populating the tables but hope it helps
table1 = {['input1'] = 0, ['input6'] = 0, ['input3'] = 0}
table2 = {['input1'] = 0, ['input3'] = 0}
newTable = {}

function tableHasKey(table, key)
    return table[key] ~= nil
end

for key, _ in pairs(table1) do
  if not tableHasKey(table2, key) then
    table.insert(newTable, key)
  end 
end

for _, value in pairs(newTable) do
  print(value)
end
```

The result is 'input6' when I run this. Which means all values not in table2 that are in table1 are now in newTable. If the values are unique between tables it's easier to compare keys than values. The final result is an indexed table where the result is stored in the value of the hash object.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local table1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
local table2 = {2,4,6,8}

for number = 1, #table1 do
    for delete = 1, #table2 do
        if table1[number] == table2[delete] then
            for i = number,  #table1 -1 do
                table1[i] = table1[i +1]
            end  --  shuffle every entry in table down
            table1 [#table1] = nil  --  erase last entry
        end  --  number == delete
    end  --  loop through table2
end  --  loop through table1

for i = 1, #table1 do print( table1[i] ) end
```

1
3
5
7
9

Answer (score -1):

The other answers listed here seem correct, but they seem a little too aggressive on memory or time complexity. Here's my take on a filter function optimized for lists of numbers.

```
-- t1 : table, the original set of values
-- t2 : table, the set of values to remove from t1
-- returns : table, a subset of elements from t1 not found in t2
local function filter(t1, t2)

    -- Assumptions :
    -- 1) t1 and t2 are arrays, not dictionaries
    -- 2) t1 and t2 do not have mixed indices or mixed values
    -- 3) t1 and t2 are sorted
    assert(type(t1) == "table", "t1 expected to be a table")
    assert(type(t2) == "table", "t2 expected to be a table")
    assert(type(next(t1)) == "number" or type(next(t1)) == "nil", "t1 expected to be an array")
    assert(type(next(t2)) == "number" or type(next(t2)) == "nil", "t2 expected to be an array")

    -- Early Outs :
    if #t1 == 0 then
        return {}
    elseif #t2 == 0 then
        return t1
    end

    -- step through each list and compare each index as you go
    local filteredT = {}

    local i = 1
    local j = 1
    local sizeT1 = #t1
    local sizeT2 = #t2

    while (i <= sizeT1) and (j <= sizeT2) do
        if t1[i] == t2[j] then
            -- found a match, exclude from output
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1

        elseif t1[i] < t2[j] then
            -- no match, add elements from t1
            table.insert(filteredT, t1[i])
            i = i + 1

        else -- t1[i] > t2[j]
            -- no match, ignore elements from t2
            j = j + 1

        end
    end

    -- we've made it to the end of one of the lists, add the rest of t1
    for i = i, sizeT1, 1 do
        table.insert(filteredT, t1[i])
    end

    return filteredT
end
```

This solution doesn't have unnecessary loop iterations and a number of early outs for optimization.

```
local a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
local b = {2,4,6,8}
local result1 = filter(a, b)
print(table.concat(result1, ", ")) -- 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

local c = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
local d = {"c", "d"}
local result2 = filter(c, d)
print(table.concat(result2, ", ")) -- "a", "b"
```